# Beego get response body in middleware after processing

Tags: json, http, go, response, beego

I have to append parameter in JSON response after request processing is completed and before sending. I can do in `after exec` filter. Here I defined filter like this,

```
beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.AfterExec, AddRequestAfterExec, false)
```

Now in this `AddRequestAfterExec` method, I am unable to read JSON response. I need to read JSON response and add parameter to it. I searched many things, but did not find any thing useful. So far I have left it empty.

```
func AddRequestAfterExec(c *context.Context) {}
```

Can anybody help, how to read Response in this function and modify it?

Also I am sending response from API controller like this

```
authController.ServeJSON()
```

Comment: I have the same trouble here, and i cant figure out why, even if tou call c.Output.Body() it doesn't append the data